# How do I fix scrollview crashing Android app?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

New app developer here. I started working on an app a few days ago. It worked completely fine until I replaced the default  to scroll view. I'm trying to make a scroll view with a design similar to reddit, the endless boxes with a set size. After changing the code, I expected multiple boxes that are the same size in scrollview. Instead, it crashes immediately on startup.

I tried changing the dimensions on the scrollview and I tried adding child elements but its still not working for me

I get the following error message in logs:

```
 **2019-11-23 20:41:40.155 10846-10846/com.john.chanapi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.john.chanapi, PID: 10846
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.john.chanapi/com.john.chanapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.john.chanapi.MainActivity@1850938 does not have a NavController set on 2131230867
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.john.chanapi.MainActivity@1850938 does not have a NavController set on 2131230867
at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
at com.john.chanapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

My content_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#312F2F"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="124dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>**
```

Mainactivity.kt file:

```
    package com.john.chanapi

    import android.os.Bundle
    import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
    import androidx.navigation.findNavController
    import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
    import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
    import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
    import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    import android.view.Menu
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new, R.id.nav_rising,
    R.id.nav_top, R.id.nav_inbox, R.id.nav_message
    ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
    }
```

Any help or suggestions would help me out a ton. I've been stuck on this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the endless boxes, use `RecyclerView`. Here is a great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118
Also, I think its better if you learn Kotlin instead of Java for android development. For both ios and android development, you can learn flutter/ It allows you to program an app for both ios and android using the same code.

Comment: Ill check that video out! I Just switched over to RecyclerView. I plan on learning kotlin, but i might have to check out Flutter.

Comment: From your logcat it seems there is an issues with getting the `NavController`. Have you added a `NavController` ?

Comment: I don't think I have a navcontroller setup for RecycleView. I don't know alot of kotlin. How do I add a NavController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logs, it is crashing at `findNavController` which is this line in your `MainActivity`: 

`val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)`.

The activity is just inflating the views in `onCreate`, when you try to get `NavController` it will fail.

One simple way to verify this is to `comment`/`delete` the code after this line in `onCreate` and check if the app crash.

If this is the issue, you can move these code into `onViewCreated` where all the views are inflated.

You can try this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new, R.id.nav_rising,
            R.id.nav_top, R.id.nav_inbox, R.id.nav_message
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: I commented out the code below **val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)** on the bottom of the page but it kept crashing. I also tried commenting out all the code below the onCreate on top of the page and it fixed the crash, just my screen was white.

Comment: Did you comment out the line itself: `val navController = findNavController(R.id.scrollview1)`?

Comment: If the app does not crash when you comment our all the code in `onCreate`, you can move those code into `onViewCreated`, that is where we usually initialize the views as the views are not yet inflated in `onCreate`.

Comment: I don't have onViewCreated in MainActivity. Do I replace onCreate with onViewCreated on the top of the page? Sorry if I'm having troubles understanding. I'm new to developing apps.

Comment: `onViewCreated` is another function that you can override from `Activity`. I recommend you to read more about `Activity` lifecycle. I will update my answer with the code as it's easier to understand.